# Vibration marks when printing slowly on Y-axis

Tags: print-quality, anet-a8, y-axis, ghosting

My Anet A8 prints come out with vibration marks when I print under 80 mm/s.

Above that value, it's fine.

Has anyone experienced something like this with any axis?

The Y-axis motor also vibrates when the belt is removed, so I'm not sure if it's a board, motor or frame problem.

I haven't changed the motor yet, I just finished checking the linear rods and ran some tests.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide images, preferably calibration cubes and post them online by [edit]. Know that 80 mm/s is pretty fast, it should do better at lower speeds. Are the belts properly tightened?

Comment: in this case you might want to print some kind of oscillation test - a wall with a 0.5mm cut in it

Comment: @Oscar: I don't have a part right now that show that significantly. It's like ringing, lasting 100mm in the part. I noticed it printing some L shaped brackets to support the middle section of a plexiglass sheet. The belts are ok, and I think I notice the vibration when I run the stepper without the belt.

Comment: @Trish: that's a nice idea, I'll do that. First I'm going to swap the stepper motor, and see how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: @avc actually, if it is ghosting changing the stepper *nothing* will change. try https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2855929 - that tests pretty much all ghosting variatons.